# tensorboard does not show accuracy and loss plot on validation set

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I'm new to machine learning, I'm trying to make an image classifier, the model is training correctly but the problem is on tensorboard, how to visualize the plot of loss and accuracy on the validation set? The only thing you see is the loss and accuracy on the test set

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                                optimizer='adam',
                                metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X, y, batch_size=32, epochs=5, validation_split=0.3, callbacks=[tensorboard])
```

[image]

Comment: By looking at those runs you have, I can see tere are `train` and `validation` runs. What do you seek? They are on the same plot with just different colors.

Comment: from small tests that I had done previously tensorboard showed me four different plots the first two with accuracy and loss on the training set and the second two with accuracy and loss on validation set. I preferred to see four distinct plots than just two plots.

Comment: I think in tensorflow v1.x train and validation metrics/losses were plotted separately and in tf2 they got merged. Does it address your case?

Comment: Yes I think you are right because between one test and another I updated tensorboard. Is  there a way to show 4 plots?

Comment: Not that I know of.

Answer (score 1):

The model runs that say '/validation' are the ones which are for the validation runs for that particular type of model.